# Mapping MVC3 model to MSSQL 2008 View using code first and database first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-view, ef-database-first

In SQL Server 2008 I have a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW products AS
   SELECT a.ID, a.Name, b.ID as SubID, b.Name as SubName
   FROM main_product as a 
   INNER JOIN sub_product as b on a.ID = b.mainID
```

This is my model:

```
Public class Products
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int SubID { get; set; }
    public int SubName { get; set; }
}
```

Now how can I map my MVC3's view to the SQL Server view?

**UPDATE**

I tried with this:

```
 public class PartialContext : DbContext
 {       
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
     }

     public DbSet<Test> Test { get; set; }

     public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
 }
```

and Controller:

```
public class ViewController : Controller
{
    private PartialContext db = new PartialContext();

    //
    // GET: /View/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Products.ToList());
    }
}
```

This effort gave me an error: "Invalid object name 'dbo.Products'."

**EDIT 2**

Just to clarify. I want to use both `code first` and `database first` technique. It means I want to create both database and model class manually, not through code generator or database generator

**UPDATE**

Problem solve. I make a mistake on naming model class

Comment: Regular entity, use it like a regular Table, exactly the same

Comment: How are you accessing your data? Raw ADO.NET? Entity Framework? Something else?

Comment: I'm using Entity Framework

Comment: AFAIK you cant insert data in the sql VIEW so there is not point in mapping the mvc view on to the db view

Comment: I want to map mvc view with db view for front end read only purpose

Comment: @DoanCuong - your question isn't about MVC at all, but rather Entity Framework code first and views, so I've modified your tags so it might get seen by people that actually know something about this.

Answer (score 5):

update the EF model

[image]

now simply you can query the view like

```
 using (var ctx = new YourDBContext())
  {
    var result = from t in ctx.product
                 select new Products{
                   ID= ctx.ID,
                   Name=ctx.Name
                 };    
  }
```

more information on the following link

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1990/how-to-use-sql-server-views-with-the-entity-framework/

I think it will help you.

Comment: That really helpful, but I'm looking for the way to use `code first` and `db first` at a same time. I mean that I want to create the model class manually, not through the code generator